# jq disable converting to unicode

Tags: json, jq, unicode-escapes

I have a simple JSON file like:

```
{
    "name": "This is a sample",
    "resources": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "obj": [
                {"data": "attribute 0 \u003e"},
                {"data": "attribute 1"},
                {"data": "attribute 2"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "obj": [
                {"data": "attribute 0"},
                {"data": "attribute 1"},
                {"data": "attribute 2"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "obj": [
                {"data": "attribute 0"},
                {"data": "attribute 1"},
                {"data": "attribute 2"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to remove the "data" tags whose value is "attribute 0" in "obj" array in the objects whose "id" is 1. I used the below command and I got the output as expected.

```
 jq 'del(.resources[] | select(.id== 1) | .obj[] | select(.data== "attribute 0") )'
```

But the problem is the character `\u003e` to it's unicode format `>` (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3e/index.htm). But I don't want that to happen. Is there any way using which I can prevent the conversion of these elements to unicode?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would matter, and it would take a great deal of effort. Internally, `jq` converts everything to an actual code point, and it would have to remember which characters were decoded in order to reencode them on output. `\uXXXX` is only necessary for non-ASCII characters; why do you think `\u003e` is preferable to `?`?

Comment: To be clear, the JSON values `"\u00e3"` and `">"` represent the *exact* same data; there's no semantic distinction between the two.

Comment: From `man jq`: jq usually outputs non-ASCII Unicode codepoints as UTF-8, even if the input specified them as escape sequences (like "\u03bc")

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to force jq to round-trip the input exactly, but you certainly can use the `--ascii-output` option to make sure that *all* its output is ASCII, and any non-ASCII characters inside strings are suitably escaped. I guess it depends on what you're trying to do. If you want to absolutely minimise unnecessary differences between your input and output, it's probably little help. But if you simply want to avoid having UTF-8 in your output, this is what you need.